# DataSpell - save state like in RStudio?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dataspell

Is it possible to save the Jupyter variables in DataSpell similar to how this works in RStudio?

At the moment, after I closed DS, I need to recompute everything. Of course I can write the main variables to disk myself, but I don't want to do that for all variables all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest thing to the save/load workspace behavior in RStudio is the `%store` magic. IPython provides the `%store` magic, but `%store` is available in Jupyter Notebooks in DataSpell.

Here is the `%store` documentation: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html

Comment: Yep, looks like that the best way, although you have to specify exactly which variables to store which is way too cumbersome. Hopefully they'll implement something like in RStudio sometime...